# TOP LEVEL VS LEADING

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Of the two adjectives, Top-level and leading, which one is stronger?

Which journal is more prestigious, a top level one or a leading one?

Comment: i am talking about scientific journal here.

Answer (score 2):

Leading is stronger, especially for a scientific journal.  It indicates that the journal's authority is in it's relevance and contribution to modern society.

Top-level simply implies that it is an established publication, which may not always be the highest quality or most modern.

Comment: but the dictionary says that top-level involves those of the highest authority.